# How to Reduce the noisy While Scale a Image/Picture with Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, graph-algorithm

I use the code just like:

```
void MyLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPainter painters(this);
    /*对img进行平滑缩放*/
     int image_width,image_height;
     image_width = width();
     image_height = height();
     QImage result = img.scaled(image_width<<2,
         image_height<<2).scaled(image_width,
                image_height,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation
                );
    painters.drawPixmap(0,0,image_width,image_height,QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    }
```

I want to scale a image to the size what I want, but when I scale it to Non equal proportion , terrible things happened ,noisy is huge ,and the image/picture just like this:

[image: Image1]

And i want to know how to get a way scale a image/picture like this instead:

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is because you call `QImage::scaled()` twice, first to upscale to 4× the desired size and second to your actual desired size.  The first call uses the default value for the transformation mode (which is `Qt::FastTransformation`).  So essentially you're combining a non-smooth and a smooth transformation.  Note that the first transformation should be unnecessary anyway.  Just scale to the desired size immediately, using `Qt::SmoothTransformation`.

```
QImage result = img.scaled(image_width, image_height,
                           Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
                           Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

**EDIT**: Just noticed something else.  Look at your `drawPixmap` line:

```
painters.drawPixmap(0,0,image_width,image_height,QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

You're drawing the original `img` when you meant to draw `result`:

```
painters.drawPixmap(0,0,image_width,image_height,QPixmap::fromImage(result));
```

Comment: Yeah,thks a lot  , I just  modify my code again ,but it's no improment , it's just like the image1. so i think it's  no key point !

Comment: but I have another question now ? can you help me ?  it's just  for a huge map , 10000*2000 ,how can I to display in my label ? i try it for a long time ,but it's not work .

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Qt, unfortunately. But the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/) has plenty of tutorials that might help you. If you can't find anything there, I recommend asking a separate question.